# How can I make a 'keydown' event block a 'keyup' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a zip code resolver and I'm using a `keyup` event handler to track when the length of the input reaches 5 then query the server to resolve the zip code. But I want to keep the script from being unnecessarily being called, so I was wonder if there were a way to track a `keydown` event and stop the `keyup` event when there is already 5 characters in the textbox (which would indicate that a query has probably already been submitted), if there were a way to stop the `keyup` event handler after? I know this is kind of a weird question so feel free to ask questions. Here kind of a layout of what I'm talking about:

```
$('#zip_resolver').live('keydown', function(event){
    if($(this).val().length==5){
        //STOP KEYUP EVENT
    }else{
        //DO NOTHING
    }
});
$('#zip_resolver').live('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val().length==5){
        //SEND RESOLVE REQUEST
    }
});
```

Comment: not sure if you already know this, but there are min/max character length options on input fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just enforce that the keydown was 4: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/H7PhT/1/

```
$('#zip_resolver').live('keydown', function(event){
   wasfour = (4 == $(this).val().length);
});
$('#zip_resolver').live('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val().length==5  && wasfour){
        //SEND RESOLVE REQUEST
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a keydown event, how about having a boolean flag that you check in keyup to decide if you have to do a resolve?

Something like:

```
if (doresolve && length == 5) {
   resolve();
   doresolve = false;
} else if (!doresolve && length <> 5) {
   doresolve = true;
}
```

That way, when you edit the field, the resolver check is redone.